# Laptop sans battery with cooling fan blowing into it?

Tags: laptop, battery, fan, compaq-laptop, cooling-pad

I just removed the battery from a Compaq Presario CQ60 laptop since it only lasts for about a minute when fully charged.
Is there any problem with using the laptop on top of a cooling pad/fan since the battery cavity has a few holes where a bit of inner components (RAM/Motherboard or whatever) can be seen, meaning that the fan will be blowing directly into there?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't recommend running a laptop without a battery unless the manufacturer explicitly says that it's okay to do so. Without a battery, when the CPU suddenly draws more power, the voltage sags (due to inductance in the cable between the laptop and its power supply). The sagging voltage causes the current to spike, which can cause premature failure of VRM components in the laptop or, if you're lucky, just cause the CPU to throttle. The battery holds the voltage up until the current from the power supply stabilizes.

Answer (score 0):

No, extra airflow should not harm your computer, but keep in mind that exposure of the internal components is not a great idea, because dust and other foreign objects can enter. It may also increase the risk of ESD (Electrostatic discharge) damage, if something were to come in contact with the internal components thru the openings.

Comment: Thank you. So in light of the concerns you raise, would keeping the battery in be better, even though the computer is always plugged in?

Comment: Yes I would keep it in, also in light of the point raised by David Schwartz above.